# Responsive multi item carousel: content doesn't fit in its viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to customize  Sorgalla carousel styles but experiencing some difficulties -  more exactly, with the right border of the last list item which is shown in the viewport of the carousel. It is simply disappearing, please take a look at it:

http://jsfiddle.net/orinoco_omi/cy7y9j7x/

Here is HTML Code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
            <div class="jcarousel">

                <ul>
                    <li>

                    <a href="#"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
     <h4><a href="#">Check-up and evaluation services</a></h4>
      <p>A nice & short description of the service  </p>                       
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
      <h4><a href="#">Check-up and evaluation services</a></h4>
      <p>A nice & short description of the service  </p>                         
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
         <h4><a href="#">Check-up and evaluation services</a></h4>
      <p>A nice & short description of the service  </p>  

                <p>A nice & short description of the service  </p>                    
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
          <h4><a href="#">Check-up and evaluation services</a></h4>
      <p>A nice & short description of the service  </p>                         
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="Image 5"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="Image 6"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

            <p class="jcarousel-pagination"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any margin I set out for the li items (I want them to be separated like here, http://comtechguys.com/slider1/index.html) causes the disappearing of the right border. I guess the problem is in .jcarousel div. I tried to set padding to it, so that my list could fit in, but useless. I also tried to change it's size, set margins... didn't help. Is there anything I am missing out?